# is it possible to open the html page pre-filled by loading it from a text file using php or javascript without database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a html form layout, and i want it to be pre-filled with exact inputs when i load the page, and this data should come from a text file on my computer, and is this possible to achieve without using any database ?

I know it is possible with a db, but is it still possible without db to match the exact ids and input the matter from the text file in the exact input spaces ?

for example:
i have the following html and js code,

jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/TphFG/

HTML:

```
      <th>Project Title: </th>
  <td><span class="dropt">
  <input id="projecttitle" onkeyup="ProjectTitleValidate()" v type="text" maxlength="50" name="projecttitle" title="Project Title for reference!">
  </td>
```

JavaScript:

```
        function ProjectTitleValidate(){
       $projecttitle = document.getElementById("projecttitle").value;
       if(/^$/.test($projecttitle)) {
           alert("Cannot be empty! Title for the project is required.");
       } 
           }
```

and i have the text file:

```
     Project Title: Temp_1234
```

i want to fill the input box in html with this value, Temp_1234.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You'll have to read the files and parse the contents manually in some way, or include a page that contains valid php code. If you are asking us to write that code, then you should show more effort and try to do it yourself first. At the current point your question is too broad and it is unclear what the specific problem is you are facing.

Comment: If by 'my computer' you mean 'the webserver, then the answer is yes and you will probably want to have a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php. If you mean the actual client computer, then the answer is know, due to obvious security reasons

Comment: @PeterVR -- Know != no :D

Comment: My mistake, know == NO in my comment though. Bloody english...

Comment: i know with file_get_contents, we can read the text file directly, but my question is if there is a lot of content in the text file, but i want to grab only the content which is useful for me and put it in the exact place or input box in the html page ?

Comment: You're talking about seeking and indexing the file which are stuffs managed by a db. You can use Sqlite. Is a database and still is a file.